# What is the default `perl` print target?

Tags: perl

I was assuming that `print "foo"` is just a shortcut for `print STDOUT "foo"`.

However I noticed that (at least) in combination with the `-i` switch this assumption no longer holds:

```
perl -ni 'print $_' file
```

this simply does not change the content of the file.

```
perl -ni 'print STDOUT $_' file
```

This however prints the content to the terminal and leaves the file empty.

Therefore the question: What is the default target of print? I.e. where does the first print print to?

`perldoc -f print` says:

> To set the default output handle to something other than STDOUT, use the select operation.

Obviously perl internally used the select operation to set the default output handle to something else. Is there any way to explicitly specify the current default output handle?

This would allow me to write something like

```
perl -i -wne 'print {/b/ ? STDOUT : XXX } $_' file
```

to build a `grep` which removes all printed lines.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for the ` -i` flag? What did you learn?

Comment: Yes, I first looked for the `-i` option in `man perlrun`. I couldn't find the answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default filehandle for `print` is controlled by the [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) function.  It defaults to `STDOUT`, but can be changed at any time.

To quote [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html):

> - select FILEHANDLE
> - select
>
>   Returns the currently selected filehandle. If FILEHANDLE is supplied, sets the new current default filehandle for output. This has
>     two effects: first, a `write` or a `print` without a filehandle default to
>     this FILEHANDLE. Second, references to variables related to output
>     will refer to this output channel.

If you look at the [documentation for the `-i` option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*%5B_extension_%5D), you'll see that the expansion includes the line `select(ARGVOUT)`.  That's what causes output to go back to the file you're editing.

ARGVOUT is special only during `-i` processing, but it does work there:

```
$ cat foo
a1
b1
a2
b2
$ perl -i -wne 'print {/b/ ? STDOUT : ARGVOUT } $_' foo
b1
b2
$ cat foo 
a1
a2
```

You can also use `perl -i -wne 'print {/b/ ? STDOUT : select } $_' foo` since ARGVOUT will be the currently selected filehandle.

Comment: ARGVOUT is special only during execution of code under `-i`.  I'm sorry if you thought I implied otherwise.

Comment: Use `select` with no argument to get the currently selected filehandle.

Answer (score 0):

It prints to the currently-selected handle, which is `STDOUT` by default. You can change the selected handle yourself using the one-argument form of [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#select), and in-place editing mode `-i` flag / `$^I` automatically selects the destination file for you (see the description of `-i` in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for code equivalent to what `-i` does).